# Why 这么 / 那么 are placed before the action verb?

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-structure, syntax

I have some confusion with the use of 这么 (*this, so*) and 那么 (*that, so*). I found these examples (from Pleco):

> 大家都**这么说**。
>
> Dàjiā dōu zhème shuō.
>
> Everyone says **this / so**.

> 你不该**那么做**。
>
> Nǐ bù gāi **nàme zuò**.
>
> You shouldn't do **that**.

where 这么 / 那么 are placed *before* the action verb. Grammatically, I understand they are **pronouns** acting as the **object** of the verb. However, in Mandarin typically the object goes *after* the verb. What is the rationale for placing 这么 / 那么 before it? Are they an exception to the standard order of `verb + object`?

Comment: [这么 +v ] = [v + like this/ this way] ; [那么 + v]  = [v + like that/ that way]

Comment: @TangHo Ah ok, so then grammatically they are like an adverb and are placed before the verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[这么 +v ] = [v + like this/ this way]

[那么 + v] = [v + like that/ that way]

Example:

大家都[**这么**][说] = everyone [says it] [**like that**]

你不该[**那么**][做] = you shouldn't [do it] [**like that**]

~

[这么 + adj ] = [ this + adj]

[那么 + adj ] = [ that + adj]

Example:

[**这么**][坏] = [**this**][bad]

[**那么**][好] = [**that**][good]

Comment: Maybe for completeness, could you provide an example with 这么 / 那么 + verb + object? Does it sound good 你不该那么做菜 - *You shouldn't cook the dish like that.*?

Comment: 做菜 in 你不该那么做菜 can be a single  verb for 'cook' but you can treat 做 as a verb and 菜 as an object

Comment: In SWC, the correct structure is [那样 + v + object ], but many people use 那样 and 那么 interchangeably.  I tried to argue [那么 +adj ] and [ 那样 + v ], but they just insist  [那么  + v ] = [ 那样 + v ], So I gave up and accepted the way they use  那样 and 那么 interchangeably

Comment: What does it mean SWC?

Comment: Standard Written Chinese